# I need to create a malloc array of strings and print those strings out

Tags: c, malloc, c-strings

important: I don't have a deep understanding of malloc so try to put things as simple as possible
Greetings, I want to create a dynamic array of strings (using malloc) and then print those strings out (for starters).

That's what I have

```
int main(){
    char **namesofcolumns = malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        namesofcolumns[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    }
    int count = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("Enter %d column name\n", count);
        scanf("%s", namesofcolumns[i]);
        count++;
    }
```

I probably have errors here already. How do I print entered strings out?

Comment: Printf wants a `char*`. Ask yourself what the types are of `namesofcolumns` and `namesofcolumns[i] `

Comment: Try using another `for` loop and `printf ( "%19s", namesofcolumns[i]);` That will right justify each string in a 19 character wide field on the same line. Also use `scanf ( "%19s", namesofcolumns[i]);` to prevent entering too many characters into each string.